# Arbitrary data type in a C++ class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I would like to make a class to store auxillary data in arbitrary objects - what is a clean way of doing this?

```
class A{
    std::string _name;
    int _val;
    void * _extraData;

    //I want to implement these methods
    void setExtraData(void * data){
        //
    }   

    void * getExtraData(){
    }   
};


class B{
    std::vector<A *> v;

    void foo(){
        //use A here - _extraData will      
        //be a (say) a vector<int>
    }
};
```

Comment: … but proper indentation is better.

Answer (score 7):

I would start with `boost::variant` if you have a known set of types or `boost::any` if not. You can always evaluate your design and see if polymorphism with an abstract interface can solve your problem too (sometimes it doesn't help). More details about the real problem you're trying to solve could help elicit better answers.

Comment: @Mark Thank you - I actually do not have a known set of types - that could be arbitrary. The aim is to have a cleaner implementation than class B maintaining the auxiliary data for each instance of A.

Answer (score 0):

templates, if you know at compile time which data type is going to be used:

```
template typename T
class A{
  std::string _name;
  int _val;
  T _extraData;

  void setExtraData(T data){
  }   

  T getExtraData(){
  }   
};

class B{
  std::vector<A<int> *> v;
  void foo(){
  }
};
```

If you don't know at compile time, i.e. it depends for example on user input, than a `union` or `boost::any` (as proposed by @chris) is the solution.